# How do you get a field related by OneToOneField and ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

How do you get a field related by OneToOneField and ManyToManyField in Django?

For example,

```
class A(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField()
    as = models.ManyToManyField('self')
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

If I want to get a 'myfield' and all associated 'as' using class B, given a 'myfield' equal to a string like 'example', how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

**Models.py**

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name
```

Let create a place instance.

```
p1 = Place.objects.create(name='Demon Dogs', address='944 W. Fullerton')
```

Then create a restaurant object.

```
r = Restaurant.objects.create(place=p1, serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
```

Now, to access place from Restaurant:

```
>>> r.place
 <Place: Demon Dogs the place>
```

vice-versa to access Restaurant from place

```
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>
```

I did not understand the many-to-many field part can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

First you get an instance of B say `b` and you can easily access `myfield` and `as` through the `a` attribute of `b`

```
b.a.myfield
b.a.as.all()
```

Furthermore, `CharField` requires a max_length attribute as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    as = models.ManyToManyField('self')
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

A general point, give more descriptive names to your models and their attributes, or at the very least, add comments explaining what these models represent